# Jython binary error on execution

Tags: jython

As soon as I execute `jython` binary, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 444, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 431, in main
    os.execvp(command[0], command[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 370, in _execvpe
    func(file, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It is not clear for me which file is missing here, but what is stranger is that it can be executed from Eclipse with no problems.

Any idea? I'm a bit lost here

Answer (score 2):

Check your JAVA_HOME environment variable. Mine was pointing to a non-existing Java installation.

Broken:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=bad path
$ jython2.7.0/bin/jython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 444, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 431, in main
    os.execvp(command[0], command[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 370, in _execvpe
    func(file, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Fixed:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/java/jdk1.8.0_121
$ jython2.7.0/bin/jython
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_121
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: indeed, in my case it was JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME set wrong